# What are the implications of running Task.Run() without Wait() in a synchronous method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a legacy code timer running a long a DB update query every 2 seconds, something like this

```
 private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      MySyncMethod();
    }
    
    private void MySyncMethod()
    {
      Task.Run(()=>{Run a long running DB update query});
    }
```

Assuming that we do not need a DB update result, are there any implications of not waiting the Task completion in the code above?

```
Task.Run(()=>{Update something in DB}).Wait();
```

In my understanding, when we call Task.Run() a new/available thread is taken from a thread pool and the task runs in this thread. Because we call Task.Run() from sync method, we do not remember current synchronization context and restore it when task is completed, like we do with await Task.Run() in an async method. Hence, my another question is when the task is completed, are the subsequent commands executed in the the task's thread or in the original one, i.e. MySyncMethod() thread? For example, if my method looks like below

private void MySyncMethod()

```
   {
      Task.Run(()=>{Run a long running DB update query});
     ... Do something after Task is completed
    }
```

is ...Do something ... executed in the Task's thread or in MySyncMethod() thread after Task finishes?

Comment: If you call `Task.Run(()=>{Run a long running DB update query});` your DB update query will be pushed in the queue of  `Task` and it will be run when `Task` has an available `Thread` and It's will not block your current thread. But when you put `.Wait()` it will wait until `Task` has an available thread to run you query completely and It will block your current thread. Please take a look: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs

Comment: When we call Task.Run() from synchronous method, does program control return to a callee's thread immediately after the Task.Run() call?  When task is completed, does program control stay in the Task thread? We don't have recovering mechanism of synchonization context like in a async/await method when we call Task.Run() from a sync method. Hence are my questions.

Comment: It would be good if someone tagged this to make it clear what PL (etc) is being used here.  This doesn't look technology neutral ...

Comment: What do you think it will happen if the query takes more than 2 seconds to complete on average? Do you really want to make more db requests than your database server can handle?

Comment: Good question. I would possibly re-write this code to make asynchronous timer, i.e. the next timer iteration is not executed untill DB query is completed or timed out.  Buy this would require significant code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry MBK, you have many questions so I need answer here:

1. When we call Task.Run() from synchronous method, does program control return to a callee's thread immediately after the `Task.Run()` call?

No, it depends:

- If Task has 10 threads and 0->9 queries in it's Queue then you call `Task.Run(()=>{query});` your query will be run immediately
- But if Task has 10 threads and 100 queries int it's Queue then you call `Task.Run(()=>{query});` your query will not be run immediately, your query must wait for 91 orther queries run completely

2. When task is completed, does program control stay in the Task thread?

I don't know exactly you mean, but if you just call `Task.Run(...)` you can not know whether your query can be run successfully or not on your main thread.

For me, I will nerver use `Task.Run(...)` only, I always need to know the result of query, so I will use Task.Run(...).Await() or if I don't want to block main thread, I will combine with a callback to process query result like this:

```cs
Task.Run(()=>{
 try {
   //Run a long running DB update query
   callback.onQueryRunSuccess();
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
      callback.onQueryRunFailed(e);
 }
});
```

Comment: I assume, you mean  "I will use Task.Run(...).Wait() ", not "I will use Task.Run(...).Await()"